# How to extract information from self-closing xml elements in vb.net in asp.net?

Tags: asp.net, xml, vb.net

For example,

```
<Image><URL scope="public" type="string" value"image URL"/></Image>
```

I want to extract image URL(value of URL) from this element and display the image.
How can i do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use [`XDocument`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xdocument.aspx) ([LINQ-to-XML](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb387098.aspx)):

```
Dim url As String = XDocument.Load(new StringReader("<Image><URL scope=\"public\" type=\"string\" value=\"image URL\"/></Image>")).Descendants("URL").Attribute("value").Value
```

[Check the `XDocument.Load(TextReader)` method overload documentation.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb299692.aspx)

Comment: my XML is stored as a string. when i use string variable as argument for load, it throws error - 'Attribute' is not a member of 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable(Of System.Xml.Linq.XElement)'. Also I am new to web developement.

Comment: @Aniruddha Oops, you're right about the error. Let me correct it ;)